# Equivalent of log4j code in log4j2

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, log4j, log4j2

Could anyone please help me about the below queries:

What is the equivalent of below line of `log4j` code in `log4j2`.

```
RollingFileAppender.getMaxBackupIndex()
```

How to implement rollover() strategy using the below line in log4j2 when implemented using plugin.

```
RollingFileAppender.getManager().getRolloverStrategy()
```

Thanks.